# Iterate through union of lists to correspond to each element a list of names of the lists to which the element belongs

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

Say I have several lists `L1, L2,L3` an I want to correspond to each of the elements of `Union[L1,L2,L3]` a list of list names to which it belongs.

How to do it efficiently?
I know it is silly question but to save time I decide just to ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lists = {L1, L2, L3} = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
labels = {"L1", "L2", "L3"};

Merge[Identity][AssociationThread @@@ Thread[{lists, labels}]]
```

> <|1 -> {"L1", "L3"}, 2 -> {"L1", "L2", "L3"}, 
>    3 -> {"L1", "L2", "L3"},
>      4 -> {"L2", "L3"}, 5 -> {"L3"}|>

Comment: Perfect one! Thank you again you saved me twice already, I owe you!